# How to obtain TraceId from a New Relic transaction?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, newrelic, apm

I have a Rails app that's running new relic's ruby agent v7.2 and distributed tracing is enabled. Having distributed tracing enabled lets NR create a "TraceId" attribute for every api call thats getting logged and I can see that in my dashboard. But is there a way I can obtain that TraceId and pass it on as a response header to my clients that make the API call to my Rails app?

Gone about the https://github.com/newrelic/newrelic-ruby-agent documentation but haven't really found an answer yet.

To be clear what I'm trying to do is pass on the NR Trace ID as a header to the client in my `application_controller.rb`

```
after_action :set_trace_id_header
.
.
.
def set_trace_id_header
   response.headers["NR-TraceId"] = get_nr_trace_id
end

def get_nr_trace_id
  # NewRelic::Agent.something_to_get_traceid_from_current_transaction?
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From any transaction you can run [`NewRelic::Agent::Tracer.current_trace_id`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/newrelic/newrelic-ruby-agent/NewRelic/Agent/Tracer#current_trace_id-class_method) to return the current `trace_id`:

```rb
NewRelic::Agent::Tracer.current_trace_id
=> "7e33f5a5da3495380cb2408dc0d64053"
```

This is found in [`lib/new_relic/agent/tracer.rb`](https://github.com/newrelic/newrelic-ruby-agent/blob/09990c10122e8d4267e0ac6b3102fae727d92e6e/lib/new_relic/agent/tracer.rb#L43-L52).

Beware that even though you may find a `trace_id` for a given transaction that trace may not be sent to New Relic depending on a number of factors explained in [Technical distributed tracing details](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/distributed-tracing/concepts/how-new-relic-distributed-tracing-works/). That means that you may be tracking locally `trace_id` values that are never sent to New Relic and thus not searchable in their tools.

Comment: Works as expected and intended. Thank you!